# Where is the microsoftbotframework openid information?

Tags: chat, botframework, chatbot

I'm trying to make a microsoft bot framework bot. According to:

https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/restapi/authentication/

I'm supposed to go to the following website to get the OpenID/Oauth Configuration Information: https://api.aps.skype.com/v1/.well-known/openidconfiguration. But that link doesn't seem to go anywhere... Is there somewhere else I should be looking? I tried the site given for emulators as well, but the keys I get from there don't match the key I receive with my message...

Thanks!

Comment: The SDK should take care of this for you. Is there any reason why you're trying to do this on your own?

Comment: I already have my bot written in a different language (java), as I had written it for other APIs. I was hoping that I could just make a few HTTP calls to make them all link up, rather than rewriting everything in C++ of Node.js

Comment: I just tried to GET the https://api.aps.skype.com/v1/.well-known/openidconfiguration and it responded with the OpenId metadata as described in the documentation at https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/restapi/authentication. Could you please provide more details about your issue?

Comment: Oh oops, actually it seems that perhaps I'm being blocked by my company's proxy settings. Sorry for wasting your time! :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was just being blocked by the company proxy. :(. Thanks for all the help!